# Pre-Fill html form using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanna know if it is possible to autofill an html form of a website (not local) using javascript, and if it is possible can you please put me in the right direction.

Edit : I have one mozilla extension that has some dropdowns, textareas ... from which i will get the data i want to put in the form.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, and just change the value attribute of your form elements.

Comment: Yes you can do it and no you can not do it. Those are the answers, but without details, I can not tell you which one applies.

Comment: We'll need much more info to answer this. The short answer to your question is yes it's possible. How you have the data to populate your form will determine how best to do it.

Comment: [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or UserScripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript, running on a website, cannot cause a visitor's browser to go to another website and pre-fill a form there. This would be a serious security issue.

JavaScript running in a browser extension can, but the specifics depend on the specific type of browser extension. (i.e. Chrome Extensions and Greasemonkey extensions are different).

JavaScript running on a server (e.g. via Node.js) can go to another site and fill out a form there (e.g. with PhantomJS). It can't present the filled in form to the user without acting as a full proxy though.

Comment: I am using an extension, so yeah i guess it is possible, thanks a lot for your quick answer